# passing parameters to remote ssh port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a remote server that is behind two gateways as shown in the figure. `gw1` is open to the outside world while `gw2` is only accessible from `gw1`. `Server` is only accessible from `gw2` and it can be one of a number of possible servers. I want to configure port forwarding through `ssh` such that `443` from my client machine is automatically forwarded to `2000` on `gw1`. This is not the problem. I have:

```
HostName gw1
User user
ForwardAgent yes
LocalForward 443 localhost:2000
```

And this works perfectly. Now I want `2000` from `gw1` to be forwarded to `443` on the `Server` through `gw2` when I `ssh` to `gw2`. I can do:

```
HostName gw2
LocalForward 2000 Server:443
```

Is there anyway I can pass the IP of the server as a parameter since it can be different every time?

[image: network setup]

Comment: You say that gw2 can be one of a number of possible servers. How is that determined? By DNS, so the hostname is always gw2 but it resolves to different IP addresses? Or some other way?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Server can be a number of different servers not gw2. And no. They are physically distinct servers on a private vlan with different host names. The actual server to connect to is determined by me. I want to set it up so that I can pass the ip of the server to connect to at the command line and it is passed to the config file. I should also make it clear that the config file for gw2 is on gw1, not on my client machine. Unless there’s a way I can specify which ports to forward from gw1 to gw2 in my local config file?

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is port 2000 really important here? Aren't you really just trying to forward port 443 through gw1 and gw2 to server?

Comment: Yes correct.2000 isn't important. It can be any port.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you don't care about port 2000. Your goal is really just to forward port 443 from client to server. And suppose you have hosts server1, server2, server3, ... in the role of server. If you add this to your .ssh/config:

```
Match host server*
ProxyCommand ssh gw1 nc gw2 22
LocalForward 443 %h:443
```

Then for example `ssh server1` will connect through gw1 to gw2, and forward 443 from there to server1.

What this does: The `ProxyCommand` tells ssh to connect to gw1 first and pipe standard output to `nc gw2 22`, which forwards that stream on to gw2 on port 22. That creates a tunnel for standard input on the client through gw1 to gw2:22. ssh then opens a second ssh session through that tunnel to gw2. Once that's established, the `LocalForward` forwards port 443 to server1 (`%h` being the hostname you gave on the command line).

See man ssh_config to read about Match and ProxyCommand.

Note that although the command is `ssh server1`, this really only connects ssh as far as gw2, and then just forwards port 443 from there. A shell would open on gw2, not server1. So you may want to run `ssh -N server1` instead, to avoid opening the shell, since the goal is really just to forward the port. Unfortunately there's no equivalent of -N in .ssh/config, but you could add something like `LocalCommand wait` to achieve the same thing - the shell would just wait until interrupted and there'd be no shell prompt.

Comment: These days there are better solutions than `nc`. You could use `ProxyCommand ssh -W gw2:22 gw1` instead. That has been supported by OpenSSH for many years. If you have a more recent OpenSSH version you don't even need `ProxyCommand` and `-W`, instead you can use `-J`.

Comment: @kasperd Thanks. `-w` works if you have tun devices, and rights to access them. So root only? and not on Windows for example.

Comment: I was going to ask. Can I use `ProxyJump` instead of `ProxyCommand`?

Comment: Ok so I tested this solution but I get the message "channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed" when I try to connect to 443. I think it's because I don't have administrative privileges on the intermediate gateways. Any recommendations?

Comment: The only rights you should need are ssh login on gw1 and gw2, and forwarding ports from gw2. sshd_config on gw2 should have `AllowTcpForwarding` set to `all`, `yes`, or `remote`.

Comment: Yes, it looks as though `ProxyJump gw1` would take the place of `ProxyCommand` here. (Our ssh doesn't have ProxyJump yet.)

Comment: @AndrewSchulman I said `-W` not `-w`.

Comment: @KG You can use `ProxyJump` if your ssh client is new enough to support it. It's the same feature as `-J` just a slightly different syntax. Using `ProxyJump` is simpler than using `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: @kasperd Ah, right. You should give another answer.

Comment: Ok thanks everybody. Any suggestion on how to fix the problem then?

Comment: Ok so I checked the configuration on `gw1` and `gw2` and there is no `AllowTcpForwarding` option specified in the config file. Any more suggestions?